# Build apps chooser for navigation (maps, waze, ...)

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to build an app chooser with an intent like this?

```
val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=${fromLatitude},${fromLongitude}&daddr=${toLatitude},${toLongitude}")
                val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
                val chooser = Intent.createChooser(mapIntent, ".")
                startActivity(chooser)
```

In this way, it opens directly google maps, but i want to build a chooser to select also waze.

It is important for me that the app opens with departure and arrival already set, with the coordinated specified in the URL

Comment: you can use the generic geo uri scheme to send a specific location to any map app that supports it... but i dont believe you can send both a start and end location https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme

Comment: yes i know, but i'm looking for a way to send both start and end location